# Extracting column names from an Excel Formula with a Pattern

Tags: java, regex, excel, formula

I am trying to extract the column names from an Excel Formula but all I can get with the following code is the latest name:

```
String formula = "IF(AB13=0,0,IF(+I13/AC13>100%,100%,+I13/AC13))";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(".*\\W([A-Z]+)\\d+.*").matcher(formula);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Column name= "+matcher.group(1));
}
```

I expect it to show

```
"Column name= AB" 

"Column name= I"

"Column name= AC"

"Column name= I"

"Column name= AC"
```

but it only shows "Column name= AC".

I get the fact that the first ".*" of my Pattern matches the whole first part of the `formula => IF(AB13=0,0,IF(+I13/AC13>100%,100%,+I13` but I don't know how I can let it match all the possibilities instead.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove all the `.*` and you don't really need the `\\W` unless you've also got text in that format in your formula (in which case, you'll have to remove all the stuff within quotes before applying the regex):

```
String formula = "IF(AB13=0,0,IF(+I13/AC13>100%,100%,+I13/AC13))";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]+)\\d+").matcher(formula);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Column name= "+matcher.group(1));
}
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/90EYeG)

The `.*` were consuming all the other matches, plus you don't really need to match the whole formula with pattern/matcher.

Comment: Could this be improved to work where absolute cell references have been used? References like: B$7. There may also be even more variations for cell references.

Comment: @JonM I think so. You could be using something like `\\$?([A-Z]+)\\$?\\d+` for that, if you consider all the different ways to lock a reference. Otherwise, there's the Table reference form which wouldn't be as easy then. Hmm, other possible reference might be even less easy, those that depend on the result of some formulae!

Comment: Thank you, your help was precious!

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating things. You simply want to match one or more letters and assert that it is followed by a number:

```
[A-Za-z]++(?=\\d+)
```

The first part of the pattern matches one or more `A-Za-z` and then uses a positive lookahead to assert that this pattern is followed by a number.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String formula = "IF(AB13=0,0,IF(+I13/AC13>100%,100%,+I13/AC13))";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]++(?=\\d+)").matcher(formula);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Column name= " + matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Column name= AB
Column name= I
Column name= AC
Column name= I
Column name= AC
```

Comment: What about a case where the cell reference is something like A$5?